# SQL Query across two tables only show most recently updated result per tag address

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables: `violator_state` and `violator_tags`

violator_state:

```
m_state_id
is_violating
m_translatedid
m_tag
m_violator_tag
```

This table holds the "tags" which has an unchanging row count of 10 in this case. The purpose is to list out each tag present, connect the full tag address (m_violator_tag) with its shorthand name (m_tag) and state whether it is in "violation". I need to use this table as reference because of the link between m_violator_tag and m_tag.

violator_tags

```
m_violator_id
m_eval_time_from
m_eval_time_to
m_tag
m_tag_peers
m_tag_position
```

This table is constantly having new rows added to it holding the information of what tags are in violation with a specific tag. So it would show T6 in violation with T1,T2,T9 ect.

I am looking to create a query which joins the two tables to show only the most recently updated (largest m_eval_time_from) for each tag.

I am using the following query to join the two tables but I expect m_translatedid and m_tag to match but they do not. Unsure why.

```
SELECT violator_state.m_violator_tag, violator_state.is_violating, violator_state.m_translatedid, violator_tags.m_tag, violator_tags.m_eval_time_to, violator_tags.m_tag_peers, 
                  violator_tags.m_tag_position, violator_tags.m_eval_time_from
FROM     violator_tags CROSS JOIN
                  violator_state
```

[Violation_state table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIBPc.png)

[violation_tags table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLkwW.png)

[results of my (incorrect) query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJ6qq.png)

Any suggestions on what I should try?

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Good point. I didn't know how to do so but will incorporate this formatting into future posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CROSS JOIN will give you a cartesian product where EVERY row in the first table is paired with ALL the rows in the second table e.g. if you have 10 rows in each, you will get 10 x 10 = 100 rows in the result! I believe you need to join the tables on the m_tag column and select the violator_tags row with the latest date. The query below should do this for you (though you haven't provided your question in a manner that makes it easy for me to double-check my code - see the link provided by **a_horse_with_no_name** for more on this or use a website like db-fiddle to set up your example).

```
SELECT  vs.m_violator_tag, 
        vs.is_violating, 
        vs.m_translatedid, 
        vt.m_tag, 
        vt.m_eval_time_to, 
        vt.m_tag_peers, 
        vt.m_tag_position, 
        vt.m_eval_time_from
  FROM  violator_tags vt
  JOIN  violator_state vs 
    ON  vt.m_tag = vs.m_tag
   AND  vt.m_eval_time_from = (SELECT MAX(vt.m_eval_time_from) 
                                 FROM violator_tags 
                                WHERE m_tag = vt.m_tag)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for! Also didn't know that tables can be shortened like that's helpful to know. I found the final where statement (m_tag = vt.m_tag) was not necessary and had no impact on query results. I didn't know about db-fiddle so I'll look into that and incorporate it into future posts. Thank you!

Comment: Great. Don't forget to mark the question as answered, if it met your requirements!

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that for some reason!